# How can I add method to an existing object in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm using a Processing library to build my project in Java. I use a function that returns me an object of type `PShape` (which I don't have access to source).

I need to make this object of type Shape (a class I designed that extends `PShape`).

How can I make that?

Basically I have:

```
PShape pShape = loadShape(filename);
```

Where `loadShape` is a function I don't have access to source code.

I want to somehow do:

```
class Shape extends PShape {...}
```

and then

```
Shape shape = (Shape) loadShape(filename);
```

But it won't work, once `loadShape()` will give me a `PShape`, not a `Shape`

How can I make `loadShape` returns a `Shape`?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `loadShape()` returns a `PShape`, then it returns a `PShape`. You can't make it return a subclass of `PShape`.

Easiest approach would be `Shape` either copies the `PShape` into a new instance:
e.g.

```
Shape myLoadShape(String filename)
{
    return new Shape(loadShape(filename));
    // Assumes you have a `Shape(PShape)` constructor.
}
```

or perhaps `Shape` isn't a subclass, but it contains a `PShape` data member.

```
class Shape
{
    // No one picked up my C++ syntax goof ;-)
    protected PShape pshape;

    // Using a constructor is just one way to do it.
    // A factory pattern may work or even just empty constructor and a
    // load() method.
    public Shape(String filename)
    {
        pshape = loadShape(filename);
        // Add any Shape specific setup
    }


}
```

Comment: To extend the answer: What differentiates the `Shape` class from the `PShape` class? Exactly add that into the above code for creating a `Shape` object using an existing `PShape` object.

Comment: I didn't want to use the Decorator Pattern or having the `PShape` object as a member of `Shape`.
How can I have a `Shape(PShape)` constructor and `PShape` not being a member of `Shape`?

Comment: @Zabuza, I need to add some functionalities to `PShape` object and use it in other methods (which expects a `PShape` input and returns a `PShape` object)

Comment: Well, your desired structure is not totally clear to me. Imagine `PShape` being a class `Animal` and `Shape` a class `Dog`. It directly follows that `Dog` inherits all properties of an `Animal` but a method that acts on `Animal` will not be able to use the exclusive properties of a `Dog` as not all `Animal` can for example **bark**. However you can indeed pass a `Dog` into a method that wants `Animal`. But you will not be able to cast an `Animal` to a `Dog`, a `Cat` is no `Dog`.

Comment: @Zabuza. It's the opposite I am wanting to achieve. Imagine `PShape` being a class `Dog`. I want `Shape` to be a class `Animal`. So whenever I create a `Dog` using the desired method, I want to actually create an `Animal`, because the `Dog` class only have `bark()` method (and I can't edit it) and I want to add a `bite()` method. (All the `Animal`s I'll have are going to be `Dog`s)

Comment: You can not enforce a class to which you have no access (the `Dog`) to extend from your class (the `Animal`). That would break the concept. How should the programmer of `Dog` implement `Animal` specific methods if he did not know about that as he designed the class. It could only work if your smuggled `Animal` class does not have anything in common with the `Dog` that was designed in the past. As a counter-example, if that would be possible you could enforce the `Dog` to extend from `Human`, how should that work? ^^

Comment: That being said, it is more than likely that your intend itself is improvable so I suggest you create a question where you tell what you are trying to achieve and others will eventually help in finding a better solution.

Comment: Short answer: You cannot change the return type of a method unless you can change the source of the method (which you can't). We'd need to know the whole `PShape` API to see if there is another approach but as the details we have in the question, what you want to do is impossible. One of the approaches shown here is the next best thing.

Comment: @Zabuza I have actually done that. But I liked the way the conversation was going here and I had basis to keep it up (I didn't study CS or something related, so I don't even know how to ask these questions). Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: And @John3136, the "framework" I'm using is [Processing](https://processing.org/reference/) and it isn't well documented. I'll use composition then. It makes more sense given the conditions.